# How do I setup my Cuda thread blocks and grids for eight dimensions?

Tags: cuda, dimension

I do three dimensional cuda work on regular basis but now I have a problem with eight dimensions.

How do I setup my thread blocks and grids for eight dimensions?

For example in 3d I use:

```
    grid.x=int(321);  
    grid.y=int(321);

    foo<<<grid,int(321)>>>
```

So each thread gets it’s own x,y,z address and tries to solve a problem using only that x,y,z.  and if the result is positive results get reported.  I know how to pass the memory pointers to report the results.

Now I have a new problem that I want to try values of 0 to 11 on eight different axis’s instead 0 to 321 on three.  I assume each thread should get it’s set of (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) parameters via the thread blocks, grid.

How do I map eight dimensions via grid and block sizes into my kernel?

Comment: think I have answered my own question.  I'll set the blocks to 32,32,1 and my grid to 32,32,32 and do the other three parameters inside by code.

Does this sound correct?

Comment: Are you serious? Your "values of 0 to 11 on eight different axis’s[sic]" would require 12**8 (>429 million) threads.

Answer (score 1):

2D nature of grids and 3D nature of blocks are just a convenience from NVIDIA; they might as well accept just single integers there and the hardware would work in the same way. That is why, if your problem is not inherently 2D or 3D I would suggest using a single dimension indexing and "splitting" the index where needed. Something like this:

```
int grid = 65536;
int block = 256;
foo<<<grid,block>>>();
```

and then in your device code:

```
__device__ int globalIndex() { blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; }

__device__ int index8D(int dim) { return (globalIndex() >> (dim*3))%8 }
```

In the above example, by calling `index8D(i)` you get the `i`-th coordinate corresponding to the current thread. However, the valid coordinates are only in range from 0 to 7. You will need a lot more threads to increase that range...

Be warned! Eight dimension cube with even few cells in each dimension is huge!
If your 8D space iterates only over `[0..7]` we are looking on `8^8` cells total (16777216). You may want to consider having a single thread to actually iterate over several cells.

---

To explain the internals of `index8D`: I am essentially splitting the binary representation of global thread index into groups of 3 bits per dimension:

```
101 110 001 000 110 001 101 110
```

each group now represents an index in one of the dimensions. The left-shift and modulo are used to extract the corresponding 3-bit group. (computing a modulo constant will be optimized by the compiler to bitwise operation; I left it as such for readability)

Comment: thank you CygnusX1, I see now what I needed to know.

talonmies, Have done searches on my I7 on eight axis with a range 0 to 13.  It took a week but it did it.  Surely my cuda card can beat my I7.  It is pure math with not communications between threads.

Comment: @user2475221: I am not questioning the need to do 421 million sets of calculations. I am questioning the need to use 421 million threads to do those calculations. You also probably don't need to do the calculations in a single kernel launch either  so having a complete indexing scheme for all eight dimensions probably isn't necessary either

Comment: I have a similar question to the one of to OP, I don't understand why it should be better to make a single thread integrating over several cells instead of just having many many threads ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer to my question, a short Cuda program that finds unitless equations, on eight axis. The search size on the the second line should be a odd integer greater than five. The program outputs powers of c0 h0 A0 R0 W0 G0 N0 F0 in row form.

I might be wrong but I think the structure is a old school short circuit logic structure  The threads diverge and report the right answers; and otherwise the threads just converge and run at full speed with the wrong ones!

Here is unitless equation, for the powers of the constants, that I am solving. I think the program is gnarly because the equation is gnarly. Each parenthesis group has to go to zero to make the equation true. One could use squares or abs or pure logic like my method.

(x4-x5)^2+(x3+x8)^2+(x4+x7+x8)^2+(x2+x4-x6)^2+(-2*(x4+x6)+x8-x1-x2)^2+(2*(x2+x4)+x1+x5+3*x6)^2 = 0

The code slows down for right answers; but they are rare, thus it running near full speed most of the time.  Once found, a right answer is easy to check.  All rights reserved, M. Snyder June 2013  I have have tired a range of 0 to 59 on eight axis and it ran in a few hours on a GTX 560.  Now trying a range of 0 to 95 on my GTX 480.

### If anyone can help me to get it to run faster, I would be interested...

```
#include "stdio.h"
#define searchsize 27
//nvcc helloworld.cu -o helloworld -arch=sm_21 -maxrregcount=20 -ccbin=gcc-4.4
__global__ void helloworld()
{
int x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,rlow,rhgh;

rlow=-((gridDim.x-1)/2);
rhgh=((gridDim.x-1)/2);
x1=blockIdx.x+rlow;
x2=blockIdx.y+rlow;
x3=threadIdx.x+rlow;
x4=rlow;
x5=rlow;
x6=rlow;
x7=rlow;
x8=rlow;

while (x8<=rhgh)
{
if (x4 == x5)
{
if (x3 == -x8)
{
if (x4 + x7 == -x8)
{
if (x2+x4 == x6)
{
if (-2*( x4 + x6) + x8 == x1 + x2)
{
if (2*(x2+x4) + x1 + x5 == -3*x6)
{
printf("%+4d,%+4d,%+4d,%+4d,%+4d,%+4d,%+4d,%+4d \n", x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8);
}
}
}
}
}
}
x4=x4+1;
if (x4>rhgh)
{
x5=x5+1;
x4=rlow;
}
if (x5>rhgh)
{
x6=x6+1;
x5=rlow;
}
if (x6>rhgh)
{
x7=x7+1;
x6=rlow;
}
if (x7>rhgh)
{
x8=x8+1;
x7=rlow;
}
}
}

int main()
{
int rangeofsearch(searchsize);
dim3 grid,block;
grid.x=rangeofsearch;
grid.y=rangeofsearch;
block.x=rangeofsearch;
size_t buf=1e7;

cudaDeviceSetLimit(cudaLimitPrintfFifoSize, buf);
helloworld<<<grid,block>>>();
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
return 0;
}
```

---

```
Sample Output, powers in row form.

c0, h0, A0, R0, W0, G0, N0, F0

-14, -14, +0, +14, +14, +0, -14, +0
-13, -13, +0, +13, +13, +0, -13, +0
-12, -12, +0, +12, +12, +0, -12, +0
-11, -11, +0, +11, +11, +0, -11, +0
-7, -13, -2, +12, +12, -1, -14, +2
-6, -12, -2, +11, +11, -1, -13, +2
-5, -11, -2, +10, +10, -1, -12, +2
+0, -12, -4, +10, +10, -2, -14, +4
+1, -11, -4, +9, +9, -2, -13, +4
+7, -11, -6, +8, +8, -3, -14, +6
-14, -8, +2, +9, +9, +1, -7, -2
-13, -7, +2, +8, +8, +1, -6, -2
-12, -6, +2, +7, +7, +1, -5, -2
-11, -5, +2, +6, +6, +1, -4, -2 
...
```